# How to convert Special Characters ˚˚¬…ˆøππªˆ¨¥¨∆˚ˆøø to ASCII value

Tags: ios, ios4, int, nsstringencoding

How can i convert Special Characters to ASCII i am using this to convert code             `int asc = [actualString characterAtIndex:0];

        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", asc];` but i am not able to convert the special characters anyone please help????

Comment: [ASCII does not have those characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ASCII_Code_Chart.svg). What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Hi my [project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244321/decoding-the-scanned-barcode-value-to-int-value) is like the scan the barcode and i get some value if it is Equal=2 then i need to display with == & if it is Equal=3 then i need to display with = and if the value is 4 then invalid ... Problem is Scanned Barcode are of integer value when decode using NSASCII it is displaying only till value 127 after that it is showing invalid results Eg:-if my Barcode value = 9699 resultBox value=jem then my addedResult value=jem= actualstring value=%å asc value id only showing 37

Comment: The thing is, ASCII _only_ exists for `0` through `127` -- if you want the output to have meanings for larger values, you'll have to select a different [character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding#Common_character_encodings). [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is quite popular because it can represent far more than the usual < 256 available in most other character encodings.